# What is the function of だろう?

Tags: word-usage, modality

I've seen a question:

> なんで**だろう**？

I know that なんで means 'why'. So what about だろう?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

だろう is a short form of でしょう ("one supposes").
Hence I read "なんでだろう" as "I wonder why" or "Why, do you suppose?"

Comment: Plain form, not short form. だろう isn't even any shorter than でしょう; plus, the name short form implies the plain form comes from the formal form, when it's the other way around.